# Vimeo Resumable approach using Uppy Tus failed with response code: 412, response text: unsupported version

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api, uppy, tus

i am implementing Vimeo video upload using resumable approach using `Uppy Tus`
So first i am making a call to my backend, and using Vimeo laravel package, i am creating the video,

```
$vimeoResponse = Vimeo::request('/me/videos', [
                                     'upload' => [
                                          'approach' => 'tus', 
                                          'size' => 26284326
                                      ]
                                ], 'POST');
```

in the response `$vimeoResponse['body']['upload']['approach']` is `tus` as expected.
then i am sending the `$vimeoResponse['body']['upload']['upload_link']` to my front end.

in my frontend, i am using Uppy tus as follow,

```
this.fileUploaderObject.use(UppyTus, {
     endpoint: this.uploadLink, // upload_link from backend
     resume: true,
     headers: {
         'Tus-Resumable': '1.0.0',
         'Upload-Offset': '0',
         'Content-Type': 'application/offset+octet-stream',
         'Accept': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4'
     },
     retryDelays: [0, 1000, 3000, 5000]
});
```

But when i select file, and start upload, i get error response every time,

```
Failed to upload <filename> tus: unexpected response while creating upload, 
originated from request (method: POST, url: <upload_url>, 
response code: 412, response text: unsupported version
```

i tried to insert `uploadUrl: this.uploadLink` along with `endpoint: this.uploadLink` in Uppy Tus config, but no change.

i tried to insert `uploadUrl: this.uploadLink` along with `endpoint: "https://asia-files.tus.vimeo.com/files/"` in Uppy Tus config, but i get CORS error.

can anyone please help ?